# Create index while writing to Mongo from Databricks

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, databricks

I am replacing the data in mongoDB from databricks using below query. However I want to create an index for first two filed while writing it.

```
dataset.select('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4') .write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").option("uri",connectionstring).option("replaceDocument","false").save())
```

We can do it in Mongo however it replaces the index everytime when the job runs so we have to do it there manually everytime.

Can anyone help me with ideas on how we can implement it?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One solution.
Try to import Pymongo (PyPI) and create a new DB connection… if you are using Databricks you could use python … this should work!!!

https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-create-an-index-for-a-mongodb-collection-in-python-371